# Inequality for Complex line integral

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, line-integrals

I want to prove the following inequality, where $\gamma$ is a complex path with $[\gamma] \neq0$ and $f:[\gamma]\to \Bbb C$ a continuous function
$$\biggl\lvert\int_\gamma \frac {f(z)}zdz\biggr\rvert^2<\biggl\lVert\frac 1 {z^2}\biggr\rVert_\gamma \cdot L(\gamma)\cdot\int_\gamma |f(z)|^2 dz$$

I tried proving it using the definition of the line integral and taking the absolute value of the integrand, so that I can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. I looked for different approaches but always fail to get the integral on the right hand side. Instead I get
$$\int_a^b |f(\gamma(t))|^2|\gamma'(t)| dt$$

which looks quite good for me, except for the absolute value of $\gamma'$.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the last factor on the right should be $\int_\gamma |f(z)|^2 |dz|$, which means that you already got your result. Otherwise you would compare a real number with a complex number in an inequality.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I do agree that the inequality doesn't make any sense the way it's written. I've never seen |dz|. I think the meaning you are suggesting is $\int_\gamma |dz|=\int_a^b |\gamma '|dt$ , correct?

Comment: Yes, $\int_\gamma g(z) |dz|=\int_a^bg(\gamma(t)) |\gamma'(t)|dt$ is the integral of $g$ with respect to the arc length of $\gamma$.

Comment: Can you define what $\| 1/z^2 \|_{z\in \gamma}$ means?

Comment: $\| f(z) \|_{z\in \gamma}=max_{z \in |\gamma|}|f(z)|$